How to efficiently store and retrieve data of a user MongoDB?
I am new to Express and trying to make an app that saves and retrieves user notes in MongoDB by their username. The way I am doing it is by creating an object with the user and saving the notes as an array.
Here is my code in expressJS.
router.post('/editnotes', async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body
    const { username } = req.query;
    const findUserNotes = await Note.findOne({ username: username })
    if (findUserNotes) {
        findUserNotes.notes.push(data)
        findUserNotes.save()
        res.status(201).send('ok here')
    }
    if (!findUserNotes) {
        const note = new Note({
            username: username,
            notes: [data]
        })
        await note.save()
        res.status(200).send('ok here')
    }
})

Here how it looks in MongoDB Compass.
  "username": "Dhruv70",
  "notes": [
    {
      "topic": "hello",
      "content": "world"
    },
    {
      "topic": "bye",
      "content": "universe"
    },
    {
      "topic": "xxxxxxx",
      "content": "xx"
    }
  ],
  "__v": 31
}

It works, but I don’t think it’s a good solution, as adding, deleting, and editing everything in the array can be cumbersome. Is there a more efficient method for storing data?

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question. You could have just copied the json and pasted it in your question using block quotes ```like this```.

Ok I will keep that in mind for future questions.

I don't quite agree with the other answers so I decided to write up my own here

For your current use case, it is possible to perform the upsert in 1 operation with an update with an aggregation pipeline.

db.collection.update({
  "username": "Dhruv70"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "notes": {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$notes",
              []
            ]
          },
          [
            {
              "topic": "new note",
              "content": "to insert"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  upsert: true
})

Mongo Playground with a match
Mongo Playground without a match


Another answer suggests that you might want to refactor your schema. This might be true, but that highly depends on your actual use case. If you find the query complexity of the above update with an aggregation pipeline manageable, you can just stick with the current schema. Or, if you find yourself working at notes level a lot, you might want to store notes as individual documents, instead of array entries.

Generally speaking, NoSQL prefers denormalizing data over storing data in a traditional entity-relationship model. Some NoSQL databases do not even support join/lookup. You might want to check out this MongoDB official doc to learn more about MongoDB data modelling.
For your current use case, if you decide to refactor notes as individual documents, you can have the below schema:
{
  "topic": "hello",
  "content": "world",
  "username": "Dhruv70",
  "__v": 31
  // some other fields from original user level
},
{
  "topic": "bye",
  "content": "universe",
  "username": "Dhruv70",
  "__v": 31
  // some other fields from original user level
},
{
  "topic": "xxxxxxx",
  "content": "xx",
  "username": "Dhruv70",
  "__v": 31
  // some other fields from original user level
}

You can see that information for the user is duplicated across different notes. This is what denormalization means.
Pros:

the username field can be indexed for faster lookup and update of notes
simpler query complexity. The update of notes can be achieved with a single playing update.
No lookup is required. Lookup is expensive in MongoDB and should be avoided.

Cons:

If you also work at user level a lot, you might need to handle duplication/deduplication/potential inconsistency of user data.
extra storage for extra user data

So in the end like all other design problems, there is no right/wrong answer to your data modelling problem. It is rather a trade-off between pros and cons of different options. The above is just my suggestion, based on my observation of the details you provided currently.

Thank you for the clear answer; it solved many of my doubts

The documentation says that I should use user_id for references. Is this an industry standard, or is using a username also valid?

@DhuruvBansal Again, it depends on your use case. Denormalizing the user information saves you a (costly) lookup to user collection if you just work on notes for most of the time, as the data is already stored in the notes document. On the other hand, if you are at the same time working a lot with user data, normalizing and storing them as individual documents may help. That would help with data inconsistency issues since user info is not scattered across different notes documents

I think it will need two operation for update a user note, you shouldn't create new collection for this. mongo db supports array operations, sample is given below
First find the note
const data = req.body;
const note = await Note.findOne({ username 
});
await Note.findByIdAndUpdate(note._id, {
 notes: {
  $push: data
 }
});

You are mixing create and edit note in one route, split it as /create-note and /edit-note
I think this information may help ypu

Yes you are correct, it is not the best of solutions. While your initial approach works, it can become inefficient as the array grows larger.
MongoDB's array performance decreases when modifying large arrays, thus updating individual notes within an array can be cumbersome.
A more efficient and scalable solution would be create separate collections for the users and notes, and then create a relationship between the users and the notes collection using a reference to the user (i.e., username or user ID).
This allows MongoDB to efficiently index and query notes, making operations like adding, deleting, or updating specific notes much easier and faster.
Hope this answers your question
So something like
Users
{
  "collection": "users",
  "description": "This collection stores user information.",
  "fields": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "ObjectId",
      "description": "Unique identifier for each user (auto-generated by MongoDB)."
    },
    "username": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "Unique username for the user."
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "Email address of the user (optional)."
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "type": "Date",
      "description": "The date and time when the user account was created."
    }
  },
  "exampleDocument": {
    "_id": "ObjectId('64f7ca1e4f0b8c8d2a9e57e6')",(note that this is the same id of the user document above)
    "username": "Dhruuv70",
    "email": "dhruuv70@example.com",
    "createdAt": "ISODate('2024-10-25T12:34:56Z')"
  }
}

and for Notes
{
  "collection": "notes",
  "description": "This collection stores individual notes. Each note references a user from the 'users' collection by 'user_id'.",
  "fields": {
    "_id": {
      "type": "ObjectId",
      "description": "Unique identifier for each note (auto-generated by MongoDB)."
    },
    "user_id": {
      "type": "ObjectId",
      "description": "Reference to the user who owns the note. This field corresponds to the '_id' field in the 'users' collection."
    },
    "topic": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "The topic or title of the note."
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "The content or body of the note."
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "type": "Date",
      "description": "The date and time when the note was created."
    }
  },
  "exampleDocument": {
    "_id": "ObjectId('74b9ca1e4f0b8c8d2a9e57e7')",
    "user_id": "ObjectId('64f7ca1e4f0b8c8d2a9e57e6')",
    "topic": "hello",
    "content": "world",
    "createdAt": "ISODate('2024-10-25T12:34:56Z')"
  }
}

You can now update a single note by it's respective _id and when fetching all notes that belong to a user, you query the notes collection with the user_id

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

How should I go about creating a relationship between the user and notes collections? I understand that user information such as name, address, password, and other private information should be stored in a different data collection.

@DhuruvBansal I have updated my answer with some code snippet to further help you understand. Hope this helps
